# R: functional approach to multiple consecutive gsub

Tags: r, functional-programming, lapply, gsub

I've been wrapping my head around this for a while, trying plenty of varieties of `map`, `Reduce` and such but without success so far.

I am looking for a functional, elegant approach to substitute a sequence of `gsub` as in

```
text_example <- c(
    "I'm sure dogs are the best", 
    "I won't, I can't think otherwise", 
    "We'll be happy to discuss about dogs",
    "cant do it today tho"
)

text_example %>%
    gsub(pattern = "'ll", replacement = " will") %>%
    gsub(pattern = "can'?t", replacement = "can not") %>%
    gsub(pattern = "won'?t", replacement = "will not") %>%
    gsub(pattern = "n't", replacement = " not") %>%
    gsub(pattern = "'m", replacement = " am") %>%
    gsub(pattern = "'s", replacement = " is") %>%
    gsub(pattern = "dog", replacement = "cat") %>%
```

Into something of the form

```
text_example %>% 
    ???(dict$pattern, dict$replacement, gsub())
```

Where, for sake of a reproducible example, `dict` can be a data.frame such as

```
dict <- structure(
    list(
      pattern = c("'ll", "can'?t", "won'?t", "n't", "'m", "'s", "dog"), 
      replacement = c(" will", "can not", "will not", " not", " am", " is", "cat")
    ), 
    row.names = c(NA, -7L), 
    class = "data.frame"
)
```

(and I am aware that the substitutions performed might not be correct linguistically, but that's not the problem now)

Of course, a brutal

```
for(i in seq(nrow(dict))) {

    text_example <- gsub(dict$pattern[i], dict$replacement[i], text_example)

}
```

would work, and **I know that there are dozens of libraries that solve this issue with some specific function. But I want to *understand how to deal with recursions and problems like this in a simple, functional way***, keeping as close as possible to base R. I love my lambdas!

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: `chartr()`: is relevant if your patterns **and** replacements are single letters.

Comment: `qdap::mgsub` seems relevant. `mgsub(dict$pattern, dict$replacement, text_example, fixed = FALSE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the `qdap` suggestion, but as from the last part of my question: "I know that there are dozens of libraries that solve this issue with some specific function. But I want to understand how to deal with recursions and problems like this in a simple, functional way, keeping as close as possible to base R." I have not found any appropriate answer that satisfy this criterion. Because of this, I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you look under the hood, `mgsub` has a "*brutal*" loop. So it is not clear what the benefit is. This questions asks for something beyond that.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding on "functional": my question is not "is there a function" but "is there a functional-programming approach, i.e. passing gsub() as argument of a map, lapply, reduce... function" - something more is explaned  in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html. There are a couple interesting ideas in the other questions linked, but still... not what I am asking :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply` for a parallel apply-effect:

```
mapply(dict$pattern, dict$replacement, function(pttrn, rep) gsub(pttrn, rep, text_example))
```

(You might want to use `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following does what you want.
It is inspired in [Functional Programming](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures), the link in your comment.
I don't like the output though, it is a list with as many elements as rows of dataframe `dict` and only the last one is the one of interess.

```
new_text <- function(pattern, replacement, text) {
  txt <- text
  function(pattern, replacement) {
    txt <<- gsub(pattern, replacement, txt)
    txt
  }
}

Replace <- new_text(p, r, text = text_example)

Map(Replace, as.list(dict[[1]]), as.list(dict[[2]]))
```